# Capturing the order of occurrence of an ID in dataframe using Python

Tags: python, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID               Product 
10001             A
10001             B
10001             C
10002             D
10002             A
10001             F
10001             X
10002             N
```

What I want in output is order of occurrence of a distinct ID in consecutive row order and the counts in that occurrence:

```
ID               Product   Order_occurrence  Count
10001             A          1                3 
10001             B          1                3
10001             C          1                3
10002             D          1                2
10002             A          1                2    
10001             F          2                2
10001             X          2                2
10002             N          2                1
```

We can get the count by group by at ID and Occurrence, but not sure, how to get the occurrence, which is in the order of rows. I am not aware of anything like lag function in python.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind `Order_occurrence`?

Comment: Think there are some 50 distinct IDs in the data, Their occurrence can be at any point repeat for different products. So I want to capture the order for each ID, which might be as if ID has done different products purchase on different day. So All the products consecutive IDs are a single occurrence and increments when we see that ID again when we traverse the different rows in column ID

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't see why would `ID 10001` for `Product A - C` will get `1` and `10001 F` will get `2`.

Comment: Because Its not in consecutive order row wise. So It can be a logic as: for each ID, when rownumber-lag(rownumber)>1 then occurrence=occurrence+1 and repeat the same for each ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This builds groups of lines with the same ID, remembers the occurrences and add the group size at the end.

```
def occCount(db):
    occ = {}
    last = db[0][0] if db != [] else None
    group = []
    res = []
    for i, p in db:
        if i not in occ.keys():
            occ[i] = 0
        # Add item to group
        if i == last:
            group.append((i, p))
        # Handle change
        else:
            occ[last] += 1
            res += [ (j, q, occ[last], len(group)) for j,q in group]
            group = [(i, p)]
            last = i
    # Handle the last group
    occ[last] += 1
    res += [ (j, q, occ[last], len(group)) for j,q in group]
    return res
```

The function above accepts a list of tuples (ID, Product). 
To test it:

```
import re
s = """ID               Product
10001             A
10001             B
10001             C
10002             D
10002             A
10001             F
10001             X
10002             N"""
db = [ re.sub(r"\s+", ' ', l).split() for l in s.split('\n')[1:] ]

for o in occCount(db):
    print(o)

> ('10001', 'A', 1, 3)
> ('10001', 'B', 1, 3)
> ('10001', 'C', 1, 3)
> ('10002', 'D', 1, 2)
> ('10002', 'A', 1, 2)
> ('10001', 'F', 2, 2)
> ('10001', 'X', 2, 2)
> ('10002', 'N', 2, 1)
```

Comment: for some reason, it is not recognising split :"'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split' "

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the part from converting to tuples and back. Seems to be working!!